# Save the status of login in cookies in browser

Tags: node.js, cookies

I try to do a simple auth system with NodeJS.

I want to save the status of login (logged or not) in cookies in browser.

Can anyone read cookies and then add the same cookie to his browser and pretend he is logged?

Is this good way to save the status of login?

Comment: I recommend you look into a framework like e.g.  passport.js (http://www.passportjs.org/), which comes with a lot of code-examples client- and server-side.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the node/npm module [client-sessions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/client-sessions) (from the Mozilla team).  It allows you to create encrypted cookies that are stored securely on the client so you don't have to worry about tampering.

This does have a couple of downsides:

1. You are limited in size to what a browser will store in a cookie, generally 4K is a safe number, so if you need a session bigger than that you will need some backend storage/cache to hold it and use just a key in the cookie.
2. You cannot invalidate a cookie once it is on the client with a given expire time.  You can always use other checks and reset the expiration to now/0/etc but you have to handle that with some backend storage/cache.

I find that a combination of the cookie for authentication with whatever you use for a user database and/or a cache (like redis maybe) make for a good architecture.

Comment: Thanks! Can I do it with this way? After login, in db will be created random hash and the hash will be saved in cookies. Every webpage will ask (does cookie for user contains this hash in db) and will be offer the content by yes/no. And if the user will be logged or if the user close the page, the cookie will be expired and the hash in db disappear.

Comment: You can definitely do this. Couple of caveats though.  You have to manually make the cookie expire immediately by calling req.session.setDuration(0).  Also be sure to do this *anytime* the session is invalid or you will leave invalid (though harmless) sessions at the browser.